# solder tips(help) recommendations

Tags: soldering

I have been soldering for a lot of years, but all I had was a single 30W temp iron and no desolder gun.

Is it ok to use the wire brush on my bench grinder brush to clean my tips ?

Comment: `What kind of wire is it?` ... only you can answer that question

Comment: I recall a Japanese Engineer told me in Japan at their factory, the technicians calibrate their irons every morning. Excess temp. can accelerate solder times but also degrade (oxidize) tip rapidly. Tinning the tip and clean wipe often.

Comment: +1 - You've inspired me to write about a recent discussion with a friend, [How to kill soldering irons efficiently](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2019/05/02/how-to-kill-soldering-irons-efficiently/). In short, my friend regularly kills soldering irons within a week or so, as the tips turn into stumps. This also happens with irons that I've lent him, that worked perfectly in my hands for a year or so. After quizzing him about it, it turns out that he cleans them with an angle grinder after work! As stated in the answers below, this causes what left of the tip to get eaten away, over time.

Comment: @Greenonline I modified my post. The wire brush would remove far less material than the wheel. I bought a stainless steel pad that I use to dip my iron into. I have 2 irons. A temp adjustable one and the 30 watt one. It has a solid copper tip that I made from 6 AWG wire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern electronic soldering iron tips are plated with iron, overtop of a nickel barrier. The tip itself is made from copper.

If you abrade it with a file, grinder or emery paper etc. you will damage the tip plating and the exposed copper will quickly dissolve into the solder.

To clean the tip of flux and excess solder, a damp (not sopping wet) sponge works great.

Your wire is probably tinned (which means it has a solder coating, which may be mostly tin or tin-lead solder) copper. If you cut it off and look at the end under a magnifier you can probably see the copper color.

Of course wire can be made from any material- aluminum, gold, nickel, nichrome, silver, stainless steel, iron etc. but many of those materials are either expensive or difficult to solder with relatively benign fluxes.

Different jobs call for different styles of tip- here are a few that are compatible with Hakko soldering irons:

[image]

Comment: According to this, the tips are solid copper. http://www.instructables.com/id/Soldering-iron-tips-from-6-AWG-copper-wire/

Comment: @fixit7 They're wrong. Copper dissolves in solder, and this is why the author is finding that their tip always turns into "a crusty burned-looking stub".

Comment: I have not found that in years of using my tips. I use a 30W iron. We can agree to disagree.